# Is my C# RSA/AES/salt/IV best practices approach missing anything?

Tags: rsa, aes, salt, rijndael

While I'm no cryptographer, I do consider myself mostly up to date on the best practices regarding [a]symmetric encryption, hashes, and crypto random number generation. I've searched, and found, many posts, both here on SO, and elsewhere, relating to the persistance of encrypted data, salt, and IV. What I'm asking for, is a look over of what I'm doing, to make sure that the pieces I'm putting together, are put together correctly, i.e. securely. Here's my plan:

In C#, I'm using RSACryptoServiceProvider to generate a nice, large, keypair of 4096 bits. To persist to disk/database, I'm using the ToXmlString(true) method which includes the private key info. I then encrypt the entire Xml document with AES as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb7w85t6(v=VS.90).aspx, using a key derived from Rfc2898DeriveBytes using 10,000 rounds and 64 bits of salt generated from RNGCryptoServiceProvider. But now the issues is, storing the salt, as well as the IV. I know the salt can be public, and I'm fairly sure that the IV can be too. So, the most simple way to do things seems to be to shove them into a plain text Xml document, along with the encrypted Xml and be done with it.

Anything at all I'm missing?

Edit0: Yes the IV need not be secret: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/#sec-Nonce.

Edit1: The salt is now produced from the password (still using 10k rounds after padding to a minimum of 64 bits), so it is not persisted separately. The IV is prefixed to the CipherValue automatically.

Comment: To have a better picture of your approach my question would be, what do you plan to persist the passphrase?

Comment: The passphrase for the Aes encryption will usually be entered manually. Unfortunately, we'll have to include it in a web.config as well.

Comment: I'm curious why you persist the passphrase in a separate repository? It's just another setting for the crypto and you're probably creating and aditional point of failure.

Comment: Just a thought: so on the client side you just persist the encrypted data, and then you have either a stored procedure or web service that will decrypt such data for you, using the crypto parameters that will be stored somewhere else, where only the SP/WS have access.

Comment: The AES-encrypted RSA key will only be on the server side, the client will never have access to it. The only reason I'm using AES is that I don't want to have a valuable RSA key unencrypted anywhere, as I think the MSDN article was alluding to.

Comment: **The salt should not be generated from the password, it defeats the entire purpose of the salt (possibly except protecting against *existing* rainbow tables)**

Comment: @owlstead thank you so much for the update. I do see what you mean. I will not be generating it from the password any more.

Answer (score 0):

The IV and salt should be secure random numbers and may be stored publicly. The iteration count may be stored publicly as well, although it is normally hard coded. Be careful that you keep an upper bound on the iteration count or you may be susceptible to denial of service attacks.

So basically you are doing OK. If encrypting XML I would keep to the XML-encryption specifications, using (the proposed) GCM mode encryption if it is available. Make sure you check *all the parameters* when decrypting though.